# How do i make this image button show a frame when clicked?

Tags: lua, roblox-studio

im very new to programming in general, ive been watching tutorials and ive been trying to make a kind of computer in my game, I want the image button "Google" when clicked to make the frame "Chrome" visible, however my efforts are not working, nothing happens when the button is clicked. [Image of my studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkrZP.png)

I tried to wire a function called Open to the MouseButton1Up event with the button, however it is not making the frame visible when clicked.